# How to update data using Web Services

Tags: sql-server, web-services, xamarin.android, sql-update

I'm trying to update my data on Xamarin. Android using Web Services. When i tried the web service on browser the data is updated in SQL Server and shows a message **Account is successfully updated** But when i bind the web service in the xamarin.android. The message shows ** The account is not exist** Can you help me fix my code pls!

I've tried using Web API as well but the data is not updated instead it shows an error **Internal server error**

**Web service**

```
        [WebMethod(MessageName = "PUT")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(ReturnData))]
        public ReturnData PUT(string FullName, string Gender, string ICNo, string Address,
            string PhoneNo, string Email, string Username, string Password, string PayMethod)
        {
            int IsAdded = 1;
            string Message = "";

            // check if this account is already created
            Users myUsers = new Users();
            if (myUsers.IsAvailable(Username, Email) == 0)
            {

                IsAdded = 0;
                Message = "Account is not exist";
            }
            else
            {
                //saving into db
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(new DBConnection().ConnectionString);

                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE pmsVehicleRecord SET clFullName=@fullName, clGender=@gen, clICNo=@ic, clAddress=@address, clPhoneNo=@phoneNo, clEmail=@email, clPwd=@pwd, clPaymentMethod=@payMethod WHERE clUsername=@username");

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fullName", FullName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gen", Gender);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ic", ICNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("address", Address);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("phoneNo", PhoneNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", Email);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", Username);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pwd", Password);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("payMethod", PayMethod);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader ds = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    Message = "Account is successfully updated";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    IsAdded = 0;
                    Message = ex.Message;
                }
            }
            ReturnData rt = new ReturnData();
            rt.Message = Message;
            rt.lstIndex = IsAdded;

            return rt;
        }
```

```
    public class Users
    {
        public int IsAvailable(string UserName, string Email)
        {
            //Result result = new WebAppTest.Result();
            int lstIndex = 0;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(new DBConnection().ConnectionString);

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader reader;
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT lstIndex FROM pmsVehicleRecord WHERE clUsername=@username AND clEmail=@email");

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", UserName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", Email);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        conn.Open();
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lstIndex = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return lstIndex;
        }
    }
```

```
        private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EditText username = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
            EditText fullName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtFullName);
            EditText gender = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtGender);
            EditText icNo = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtICNo);
            EditText address = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtAddress);
            EditText phoneNo = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPhoneNo);
            EditText email = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtEmail);
            EditText password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPwd);
            EditText payMethod = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPayMethod);

            PUTWebRef.WebServicePMS webserUpdate = new PUTWebRef.WebServicePMS();
            webserUpdate.PUTAsync(username.Text, fullName.Text, gender.Text, icNo.Text, address.Text, phoneNo.Text, email.Text, password.Text, payMethod.Text);
            webserUpdate.PUTCompleted += WebserUpdate_PUTCompleted;
        }
```

```
        private void WebserUpdate_PUTCompleted(object sender, PUTWebRef.PUTCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
                alert.SetTitle("Error");
                alert.SetMessage(e.Result.Message);
                alert.SetButton("Ok", (c, ev) =>
                { });
                alert.Show();
        }
```

The expected output should be **Account is successfully updates**.
The actual output is **The account is not exist**

Comment: When you get an error you need to figure out what the error is. Posting "I got an error" is pretty useless. If the problem here is that you get the message that the account does not exist when you think you shouldn't then you start there. That code isn't posted here so no idea what it does.

Comment: i try to fix it already at the first place. It's not a big problem to ask professional to inform you the mistake. Also, i don't understand what you are trying to say. This is a platform for people to ask question related to programming. Thank you @SeanLange

Comment: Yes this is a great platform to ask questions about programming. But you didn't ask a question. You are asking us to guess what the problem might be. I don't even understand what the issue is. Is it the unknown error or that the message "account is not exist" is being returned when you think it shouldn't be?

Comment: I've mentioned already supposedly the output shows "Account is successfully updated" but when i tried on the phone the output shows vice versa. Because when i tried on the browser. The output shows the right thing. So i don't know why it turn out to be like that.

Comment: Try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a good question. Then take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to find some inspiration to make this into a good question.

Comment: You need to post the code for that method at the very least. Obviously the IsAvailable method returned 0.

Comment: If you can't help people, just tell them in a good way. Don't be rude or sarcastic.

Comment: I am not being rude or sarcastic. I am telling you that you didn't provide enough information for somebody to help here. Clearly the issue is that IsAvailable returned the value 0. You say that is incorrect. I can neither agree nor disagree because that code isn't posted. Therefore I have no idea what it does. But that seems like where the problem lies. My comments have been trying to help you improve your question so that people can help find a solution to the problem.

Comment: The only guess I could make based on the details is checking if the database you are connected to has the account you think it should. Or checking to make sure you are in fact connected to the correct database.

Comment: I have updated the question with the "IsAvailable" code. I tried already using the browser when i change the data, the database updated with the new data.

Comment: Ahh here we go. The problem is that you have an anti-pattern I call try/squelch. That is to say that you have a try/catch where the catch is empty. This makes it impossible to debug because you go to the trouble of capturing the error but the empty catch takes the exception and throws away and pretends that nothing happened. Errors happen. You just have to handle them gracefully not swallow them. I would just remove that try catch completely and the real error will expose itself quickly.

Comment: So i have to remove try and catch in the web service is it??

Comment: The try catch isn't what is causing the issue. It is what is preventing you from seeing what the issue is.

Comment: I don't understand. Was it something to do with why i can't update my database?

Comment: Your code is throwing an error. But you can't tell what that error is because your empty catch is preventing you from seeing the error. You need to let the error happen so that you know what it is. Once you do that you can fix the error.

Comment: So what should i do? Remove the try/catch???

Comment: i did some changes on the code just now. without the try/catch. The output is still the same "the account is not exist"

Comment: This one is tough, especially since you are doing this on a mobile app. Add some debugging help in your code. Log the values being sent to your query. Make sure you don't have another try/empty catch above this in the stack somewhere (doesn't look like in the code you posted though). The deal here is you have to debug the code and doing it remotely is nearly impossible. All we can really do is provide blind suggestions and see if it helps you find the problem.